# Can't get attribute value with C# XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I've spent so much time with this already, still can't get the value of NTE attribute. Can someone please help?

**C#**

```
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        XPathDocument xmlDoc = new XPathDocument(sr); // holds xml document
        XPathNavigator xmlNav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator(); //evaluates XPath expressions
        XPathNodeIterator node = xmlNav.Select("/DATA2SC/CALL");
        string dne = xmlNav.GetAttribute("NTE", "");

        Console.WriteLine(dne);
        sr.Close();
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATA2SC PIN="00000">
    <CALL
    TR_NUM="00000001"
    STATUS="WAITING_FOR_APPROVAL"
    NTE="$15.00">
        <PROBLEM>
            Text
        </PROBLEM>
    </CALL>
</DATA2SC>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code please ?

I already check and it's work

```
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:\\x.xml");
    XPathDocument xmlDoc = new XPathDocument(sr); // holds xml document
    XPathNavigator xmlNav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator(); //evaluates XPath expressions


    var node = xmlNav.SelectSingleNode("/DATA2SC/CALL");
    string dne = node.GetAttribute("NTE", "");

    Console.WriteLine(dne);
```

OR

```
    XDocument docXmlWorld = XDocument.Load("c:\\x.xml");
    foreach (var node1 in docXmlWorld.Descendants("DATA2SC"))
    {
        foreach (var node2 in node1.Descendants("CALL"))
        {
            string dne = node2.Attribute("NTE").Value;
            Console.Out.WriteLine(dne);
        }
    }
```

Or you can do like this too:

```
    XDocument docXmlWorld = XDocument.Load("c:\\x.xml");
    //Get the first child => [DATA2SC]
    XElement elementNodeDATA2SC = docXmlWorld.Element("DATA2SC");
    //Get the first child => [CALL]
    XElement elementNodeCALL = elementNodeDATA2SC.Element("CALL");
    //Get the attribute NTE from [CALL] node 
    string dne = elementNodeCALL.Attribute("NTE").Value;
    Console.Out.WriteLine(dne);
```

Comment: This works, thanks. It looks like my problem is somewhere else. I download xml content in to stream reader. That's where my problem is :(

Answer (score 0):

The `Select` method, returns a collection of all nodes with the specified XPath.

You can use [`SelectSingleNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50wkzt09(v=vs.110).aspx), to select the first node.

```
    var node = xmlNav.SelectSingleNode("/DATA2SC/CALL");
    string dne = node.GetAttribute("NTE", "");
```

Comment: I tried using SelectSingleNode before as well, unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @GvS => you do a mistake , it's should be => string dne = node.GetAttribute("NTE", "");

Comment: @MehdiBugnard, yes you are right, it was a bug hiding in plain sight